# c# google spreadhseets inputing into a specific cell

Tags: c#, google-sheets, gdata-api, google-docs

I'm trying to write to a specific cell in a Google spreadsheet using C# without having to search every single cell and see if it is the right cell.  For example, I don't want to have to search to see if "A1" is in the title of all the cells in a worksheet in order to write to A1.  In other programming languages (python) I've found plenty of examples of how to do this, but I can't find the same methods in C#.  How can I do something like:

```
cell[1,1].value = "JoMama";
```

Comment: Are you using the .NET library found here? http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

Comment: yes, I am using that.  I found the answer finally.  I guess you have to set the minimum and maximum on the columns and the rows of the CellQuery to be the same so the CellFeed.Entries array only has one member.  Then you just access that member. (see code below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Updates a single cell in the specified worksheet.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">an authenticated SpreadsheetsService object</param>
    /// <param name="entry">the worksheet to update</param>
    private static void UpdateCell(SpreadsheetsService service, WorksheetEntry entry)
    {
        AtomLink cellFeedLink = entry.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.CellRel, null);
        CellQuery query = new CellQuery(cellFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Row of cell to update? ");
        string row = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Column of cell to update? ");
        string column = Console.ReadLine();

        query.MinimumRow = query.MaximumRow = uint.Parse(row);
        query.MinimumColumn = query.MaximumColumn = uint.Parse(column);

        CellFeed feed = service.Query(query);
        CellEntry cell = feed.Entries[0] as CellEntry;

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Current cell value: {0}", cell.Cell.Value);
        Console.Write("Enter a new value: ");
        string newValue = Console.ReadLine();

        cell.Cell.InputValue = newValue;
        AtomEntry updatedCell = cell.Update();

        Console.WriteLine("Successfully updated cell: {0}", updatedCell.Content.Content);
    }
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/spreadsheets/spreadsheetdemo.cs